# Teradata Driver not available in Spark Context

Tags: pyspark, jar, driver, teradata

I am currently setting up a Package, where Spark Jobs can be tested and debugged locally before they are deployed to Databricks. For this I created a Docker Image with all the neccessary Pyspark libraries and within in the Docker Image it is possible to work with pyspark dataframes. It is also possible to get data from Databases where the Driver can be installed via Maven (I have tested it with the Kusto Database).

Now I would like to access data from the Teradata Database with pyspark. For Teradata there is no Maven package available, only a .jar file which you get from the Teradata webpage. In pyspark you can add those jars with:

```
    spark_conf = SparkConf()
    spark_conf.setAll([
                ("spark.jars", "/usr/app/terajdbc4.jar")
                ])
    
    # here a warning is send out
    #22/03/22 12:56:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your #platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    #Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    #Setting default log level to "WARN".
    #To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
    
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=spark_conf).getOrCreate()
    
    ## here the error occurs
    spark_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
                .option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver") \
                .option("url", f"jdbc:teradata://{self.dbhostip}/LOGMECH=LDAP") \
                .option("dbtable", query) \
                .option("user", self.username) \
                .option("password", self.password) \
                .option("fetchsize", 10000) \
                .option("numPartitions", partitions) \
                .load()
```

However the spark.read runs into an error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o87.load.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:460)
    at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$asProperties$1(JDBCOptions.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:468)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The same jar is used in Databricks and is there installed via the Databricks Installation functionality. There the connection is working perfectly fine.

From the Docker I can also connect to the teradata with python code via some python package.

From Docker the connection with Kusto and Pyspark is also working fine:

```
    # Here no warning is send out (compare to .jar init)
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
            "spark.jars.packages", "com.microsoft.azure.kusto:kusto-spark_3.0_2.12:2.7.3"
            ).getOrCreate()
    
    kusto_df = spark.read. \
            format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource"). \
            option("kustoCluster", self.cluster). \
            option("kustoDatabase", self.database). \
            option("kustoQuery", query). \
            option("kustoAadAppId", self.client_id). \
            option("kustoAadAppSecret", self.client_secret). \
            option("kustoAadAuthorityID", self.authority_id). \
            load().repartition(partitions)
```

Now the big question is, why is it working on Databricks to use the Teradata driver and not locally?

Comment: Perhaps because pyspark is (incorrectly) leaving its own options such as `dbtable` in the collection passed to the driver; other tools don't do that. Try appending `,STRICT_NAMES=OFF` option to the connection string.

Comment: @Fred i tried it and it still resulted in 087.load error.

Comment: Maybe dumb questions, but: Is the JDBC driver jar within (or mounted to) the Docker container? Are the referenced username / password / dbhostip values defined?

Comment: @Fred yes it is, if the jar file is not there in the init of the spark session an error occurs: WARN DependencyUtils: Local jar /usr/app2/terajdbc4.jar does not exist, skipping.
Yes the credentials are correct, I am using the same to access with teradata with a pyhton library and that is working quite fine.

Comment: SInce the error appears to be in Hashtable.put, it would seem at least one of your .option values is null / none.

Comment: @Fred finally it is working. There were two issues: one with a missing .option (you were right) and the second one was a firewall issue.